Getting unique range from SQL sequence for concurrent requests
Using Postgres I've created a sequence
CREATE SEQUENCE seq INCREMENT BY 1000;

I need to get from it boundaries of a unique range of 1000, which works with multiple concurrent requests.
Using the code shown here seems to return the needed result (for example; (1, 1001))
SELECT last_value, nextval('seq') FROM seq;

Is it going to work the right way with multiple concurrent requests?

You should read the Notes section here Create Sequence.
